# cout Not Working Reliably

Tags: c++, cout, codewarrior

I was working on a school project to make a blackjack/21 console application. The program is somewhat long and complicated, so will only put the offending code here. Complete code will be below.

```
cout << "Before comp instruct";
cout << endl << "Computer: ";
cout << "After comp instruct";
```

It will always print the first statement, but it sometimes stops immediately after that. It happens only sometimes, depending on the input in the program. I (and my teacher and peers) could not figure out why this program stops after the first statement. At least one other person in the class is having a similar problem.

These were done using CodeWarrior IDE on a Windows 7 Dell desktop.

Comment: Complete code in a comment is an extremely bad idea. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in the question would be better.

Comment: add `cout.flush();` or another `endl`.

Comment: We didn't ask for your entire program, only the code relevant to your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone, I'm new here. I'll try to get an SSCCE version up tomorrow.

Elazar, I'll try that when I get to my compiler tomorrow.

Comment: As Elazar points out, unless you flush the stream using `cout << endl << "Computer: " << flush;` (or another endl that calls flush internally), you're not guaranteed to see the output until the buffers are full and automatically flushed. Which may never happen if you're waiting for input.

Comment: @alexwho314, There are online compilers.

Comment: *"It happens only sometimes, depending on the input in the program"* - Therein, I suspect, lies your answer.

Comment: What compiler are you using that uses `iostream.h` and `vector.h`? About 10 years ago `<iostream>` and `<vector>` became the standard headers.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I will try using flush tomorrow.

Comment: @chris, I tried other compilers, but they don't work with my code. They keep saying there are errors.

Comment: @Component10, I don't see how input can affect it because there is no decision being made between the first and second statement.

Comment: @JesseGood, I'm using CodeWarrior. I think it's around 10 years old. The school hasn't purchased new programming software recently. We still use VB6 (from 1999) in class.

Comment: @alexwho314, I suggest getting rid of those errors. They're there to help you.

Comment: @chris, they are really strange errors like saying it doesn't recognize certain keywords, like return, do, or if.

Comment: @alexwho314, It's probably another error causing that. Start from the top.

Comment: @chris, the specific library I'm required to use (apstring.h) isn't compatible with newer compilers.

Comment: @alexwho314, Is that the same one used on the AP exam? That's really too bad in any case, though :/ Using really old tools doesn't really benefit anyone nearly as much and there are tons of free new solutions.

Comment: @chris, the curriculum uses the software the AP exam used to use. The AP exam has since moved on.

Comment: @alexwho314, Yeah, I wished it was still in C++ when I wrote it this year, but I noticed they killed off the string class and had GridWorld. At least the documentation for it is at the back.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I tried using flush. It finally printed the second statement, but it would not help print the third.

Comment: @alexwho314 `flush` will send all text written so far to the console. If you want the third line written, just flush at the end of that instead.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I had tried it, but it didn't help. I'm working on creating a minimal version of the problem.

Comment: @chris, I created an SSCCE version and managed to solve my program. I had an infinite loop in another portion of the program. I still am clueless about why that would prevent these statements from printing properly.